# how to make a multiple label to change multiple textbox after click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make a multiple label to change multiple textbox after click event?

**Problem:** This output only showing last textbox value.

```
$(function () {
    $('a.edit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('label.control-label1').each(function (key, item) {
            var label = $(item);
            label.hide();
            label.siblings('input.edit-input1').val(label.text()).show().focus();
        });

        //Search for .control-label items
        $('label.control-label').each(function (key, item) {
            var label = $(item);
            label.hide();
            label.siblings('input.edit-input').val(label.text()).show().focus();
        });
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Logz/n24Ud/

Comment: sorry, i dont get what you need..can you explain abit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n24Ud/1/)

That works. You were doing

```
label.siblings('input.edit-input').val(label.text()).show().focus();
```

which changed text of all input every time.

I just wrapped all pairs of label- textbox in a div like

```
<div>
    <label for="name" class="control-label">
        <p class="text-info">
            <label style="color: #662819;" id="plz">test1</label>
                <i class="icon-star"></i>
        </p>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="edit-input" />

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for solution...

Updated Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Logz/n24Ud/2/